Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 fails - No Public Key
I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 LTS using sudo do-release-upgrade and getting the following error:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,251 kB]
Fetched 1,252 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg'
gpg exited 2
Debug information:


gpg: Signature made Mon 13 Sep 2021 02:23:09 AM CDT using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found

Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.

I've downloaded every indicated key that I can find, have traced to see that the server(s) are reachable and that the ports are open. I really need this upgrade to recover information from an application on this server so I can upgrade further.
I'm rather new to Linux and had this dropped in my lap. I'm trying to learn, but also need a solution more than an education at this point.
Thanks!
--Mike

You are really late.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Please fresh install Ubuntu 24.04. You can use the live session/the existing installation to back up data from the home folder and system partition
